# Apply a transformation model (data augmentation) in images in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I am a newbie in some sequential models in Tensorflow with Python. I have a transformation sequential model like the one below. It applies randomly to a given image input some operations with random parameters.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

data_transformation = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Lambda(lambda x: my_random_brightness(x, 1, 20)))
        layers.GaussianNoise(stddev=tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0, maxval=1)),
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(
            factor=0.01,
            fill_mode="reflect",
            interpolation="bilinear",
            seed=None,
            name=None,
            fill_value=0.0,
        ),
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(
            height_factor=(0.1, 0.2),
            width_factor=(0.1, 0.2),
            fill_mode="reflect",
            interpolation="bilinear",
            seed=None,
            name=None,
            fill_value=0.0,
        ),
    ]
)
```

There is also a lambda function in this model that define as below

```
def my_random_brightness(
    image_to_be_transformed, brightness_factor_min, brightness_factor_max
):

    # build the brightness factor
    selected_brightness_factor = tf.random.uniform(
        (), minval=brightness_factor_min, maxval=brightness_factor_max
    )

    c0 = image_to_be_transformed[:, :, :, 0] + selected_brightness_factor
    c1 = image_to_be_transformed[:, :, :, 1] + selected_brightness_factor
    c2 = image_to_be_transformed[:, :, :, 2] + selected_brightness_factor

    image_to_be_transformed = tf.concat(
        [c0[..., tf.newaxis], image_to_be_transformed[:, :, :, 1:]], axis=-1
    )

    image_to_be_transformed = tf.concat(
        [
            image_to_be_transformed[:, :, :, 0][..., tf.newaxis],
            c1[..., tf.newaxis],
            image_to_be_transformed[:, :, :, 2][..., tf.newaxis],
        ],
        axis=-1,
    )

    image_to_be_transformed = tf.concat(
        [image_to_be_transformed[:, :, :, :2], c2[..., tf.newaxis]], axis=-1
    )

    return image_to_be_transformed
```

Just now suppose that I would like to apply such a model to output such random operations in one batch containing just one image and I would like to see and save the result. How is that possible to do that? is there any predict() or flow() like function to output such a result?

EDIT: I tried `result=data_transformation(image)` and I have the following error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Index
> out of range using input dim 3; input has only 3 dims
> [Op:StridedSlice] name: sequential/lambda/strided_slice/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the correctness of the brightness processing layer (above), it's coded to take a batch of images and not a single image. That's the reason it gives the expected error. You should add a batch axis while passing a single image in this case. It should work.

```
result=data_transformation(image[None, ...])
```

Also, in custom layer implementation, try always to adopt subclassing way.

```
class MyCustomBrightNess(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, pbrightness_factor_min, brightness_factor_max, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.brightness_factor_max = brightness_factor_max
        self.pbrightness_factor_min = pbrightness_factor_min
        
    def call(self, inputs):
         # build the brightness factor
      selected_brightness_factor = tf.random.uniform(
         (), minval=self.brightness_factor_min, maxval=self.brightness_factor_max
      )

      c0 = inputs[:, :, :, 0] + selected_brightness_factor
      c1 = inputs[:, :, :, 1] + selected_brightness_factor
      c2 = inputs[:, :, :, 2] + selected_brightness_factor

      inputs = tf.concat(
         [c0[..., tf.newaxis], inputs[:, :, :, 1:]], axis=-1
      )

      inputs = tf.concat(
         [
               inputs[:, :, :, 0][..., tf.newaxis],
               c1[..., tf.newaxis],
               inputs[:, :, :, 2][..., tf.newaxis],
         ],
         axis=-1,
      )

      inputs = tf.concat(
         [inputs[:, :, :, :2], c2[..., tf.newaxis]], axis=-1
      )

      return inputs
        
    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'pbrightness_factor_min': self.pbrightness_factor_min,
            'brightness_factor_max': self.brightness_factor_max
        }
        base_config = super(MyCustomBrightNess, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

---

About the correctness of this implementation, I didn't check rigorously. I would suggest using [`random_brightness`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/random_brightness) or [`adjust_brightness`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/adjust_brightness) from the official implementation. Or if you're using `tensorflow2.9`, say hello to the new [KerasCV](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-cv/blob/master/keras_cv/layers/preprocessing/__init__.py#L18-L56), there we can find `RandomBrightness` layers.